Will this over-voltage protection circuit work?
I am designing a PCBA that is powered from an AC adapter supplying + 19 VDC to the circuit. I want to add a protection against over-voltage, let's say up until + 24 VDC. I came up with the following circuit :

Explanations :

Input voltage > + 24 V => Zener diode = + 24 V => Q1 is passing => Q2 is passing => Q3 is open => LOAD is protected
Input voltage < + 19 V => Zener diode blocked => Q1 is open => Q2 is open => Q3 is passing => LOAD is supplied

Before I order the components to test it, do you see something wrong ? Is there something I should pay attention to ? Can it be improved ?

This looks like KiCAD. I believe they do have some simulation capabilities with ngspice. Have you done a simulation for this? Also, could provide more specifications on "will this [circuit] work"? Even if it does work, will it function the way you want it to?

What are the capacitors for? C1 is pointless. C2 will delay switching. C3 seems redundant. R1 can, and should be much larger. Many MOSFETs can't handle $V_{GS}>20V$, and Q3's $V_{GS}$ will exceed 20V if the supply does too.

There is no reason to use Q1, just place zener to gate of Q2. Btw , the limit voltage is zener+Vgs (not just a zener). I would use a Bjt as comparator instead of mosfet- it has more predictable Vbe.

